# How to receive full XML response with CDATA embedded XML in apex callout to SOAP service

Tags: apex, soap, xml, httprequest

I'm currently working on a project, which requires flight status information from OAG's On-Demand Flight Status information service ([WSDL](https://secure.oag.com/ws_oag_com/oagflightstatusinformation.asmx?WSDL)).

I can test the service with SOAPui. Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.oag.com">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <ws:Authenticate>
             <ws:UserId>test</ws:UserId>
             <ws:Password>test</ws:Password>
          </ws:Authenticate>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response (using proper username / password):

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <AuthenticateResponse xmlns="http://ws.oag.com">
         <AuthenticateResult>1</AuthenticateResult>
         <SecurityToken xsi:type="xsd:string"><![CDATA[<OAGToken><Username>********</Username><IssueDateTime>2015-11-05T07:12:17</IssueDateTime><ExpiryDateTime>2015-11-06T07:12:17</ExpiryDateTime><CustomerNo>********</CustomerNo><Signature>***************************</Signature></OAGToken>]]></SecurityToken>
      </AuthenticateResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I'm both interested in the AuthenticateResult value and embedded XML part within SecurityToken.

The WSDL lacks XML element types in two spots at element SecurityToken. To be able to generate apex from the WSDL, I made these elements type string (also tested token).

After calling the webservice with the generated apex, the value of SecurityToken does not contain the full CDATA contents, but a concatenation of all XML values within the CDATA embedded XML.

So I decided to manually call the service with HTTPRequest.

Code:

```
public class fc_OAGFS_OnDemand_Client {
    // TODO: Place in custom setting
    private static final String username = 'test';
    private static final String password = 'test';

    private static final String authenticateEndPoint = 'https://secure.oag.com/ws_oag_com/oagflightstatusinformation.asmx';

    public static void authenticate() {
        String payLoad = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.oag.com"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><ws:Authenticate><ws:UserId>'+username+'</ws:UserId><ws:Password>'+password+'</ws:Password></ws:Authenticate></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>';

        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type','text/xml;charset=UTF-8');
        req.setHeader('SOAPAction', ''); // Empty as in SOAPui
        req.setEndpoint(authenticateEndPoint);              
        req.setHeader('Content-Length',String.valueOf(payLoad.length()));
        req.setBody(payLoad);

        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);

        System.debug('>>> Answer String '+res.getBody());
        System.debug('>>> Answer XML Document '+res.getBodyDocument().toXmlString());
        System.debug('>>> Answer BLOB '+res.getBodyAsBlob().toString());
    }
}
```

Interesting part of debug log:

```
14:22:42.956 (3956667815)|USER_DEBUG|[47]|DEBUG|>>> Answer String 1<OAGToken><Username>********</Username><IssueDateTime>2015-11-05T07:22:42</IssueDateTime><ExpiryDateTime>2015-11-06T07:22:42</ExpiryDateTime><CustomerNo>********</CustomerNo><Signature>*********************************************</Signature></OAGToken>

14:22:42.957 (3957449646)|USER_DEBUG|[48]|DEBUG|>>> Answer XML Document 1<OAGToken><Username>********</Username><IssueDateTime>2015-11-05T07:22:42</IssueDateTime><ExpiryDateTime>2015-11-06T07:22:42</ExpiryDateTime><CustomerNo>********</CustomerNo><Signature>*********************************************</Signature></OAGToken>

14:22:42.957 (3957601751)|USER_DEBUG|[49]|DEBUG|>>> Answer BLOB 1<OAGToken><Username>********</Username><IssueDateTime>2015-11-05T07:22:42</IssueDateTime><ExpiryDateTime>2015-11-06T07:22:42</ExpiryDateTime><CustomerNo>********</CustomerNo><Signature>*********************************************</Signature></OAGToken>
```

As above log shows, only a mangled part of the response from OAG's service is returned. Salesforce performs some processing / interpretation.

How can I receive the complete response, including SOAP envelope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried replicating your issue, using both WebServiceCallout.invoke and HttpRequest. This was somewhat limited as I didn't have valid credentials to the web service. I've applied for a [trial account](http://www.oag.com/Flight-Status/Flight-Status-Ondemand), so I'll see what comes of that.

As you mentioned in the question, I needed to add a type attribute in the WSDL for the two elements named SecurityToken that were missing the value.

```
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SecurityToken" type="s:string" /> <!-- Added missing type -->
```

From there I could use Wsdl2Apex to generate the required Apex classes (OK, I actually used the [FuseIT SFDC Explorer Wsdl2Apex](http://www.fuseit.com/explorer) implementation, but the result should be the same. Disclose, this is a free tool from my current employer).

Using the following anonymous Apex it appeared to process fine (aside from the invalid credentials).

```
wsOagCom.OAGFlightStatusInformationSoap oagService = new wsOagCom.OAGFlightStatusInformationSoap();
wsOagCom.AuthenticateResponse_element result = oagService.Authenticate('UserId','Password','SecurityToken');

System.debug(result);
System.debug('AuthenticateResult: ' + result.AuthenticateResult);
System.debug('SecurityToken : ' + result.SecurityToken)
```

[image]

I also tried generating the equivalent HttpRequest. Again, no immediate issue processing the response into an AuthenticateResponse_element.

I then tried making a test case and HttpCalloutMock implementation that returned the same response that you get from SoapUI.

**Mock**

```
@isTest
public class wsOagComMock implements HttpCalloutMock {

    protected Integer code = 200;
    protected String status = 'OK';

    protected String bodyAsString = 
    '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' +
        '<soap:Body>' +
            '<AuthenticateResponse xmlns="http://ws.oag.com">' +
                '<AuthenticateResult>1</AuthenticateResult>' +
                '<SecurityToken xsi:type="xsd:string">' + 
                    '<![CDATA[<OAGToken><Username>UN</Username><IssueDateTime>2015-11-05T07:12:17</IssueDateTime><ExpiryDateTime>2015-11-06T07:12:17</ExpiryDateTime><CustomerNo>CN</CustomerNo><Signature>Sig</Signature></OAGToken>]]>' + 
                '</SecurityToken>'+
            '</AuthenticateResponse>' +
        '</soap:Body>' +
    '</soap:Envelope>';

    protected Map<String, String> responseHeaders;


    public wsOagComMock() {
    }

    public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        HttpResponse resp = new HttpResponse();
        resp.setStatusCode(code);
        resp.setStatus(status);

        resp.setBody(bodyAsString);

        if (responseHeaders != null) {
            for (String key : responseHeaders.keySet()) {
                resp.setHeader(key, responseHeaders.get(key));
            }
        }
        return resp;
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
@isTest
public class wsOagComTest {
    public static testmethod void testAccountCallout() {
        wsOagComMock fakeResponse = new wsOagComMock();
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, fakeResponse);
        wsOagCom.OAGFlightStatusInformationSoap oagService = new wsOagCom.OAGFlightStatusInformationSoap();
        //wsOagCom.AuthenticateResponse_element result = oagService.Authenticate('UserId','Password','SecurityToken');

        wsOagCom.AuthenticateResponse_element result = oagService.Authenticate_Http('UserId','Password','SecurityToken');

        System.debug(result);

        System.debug('AuthenticateResult: ' + result.AuthenticateResult);
        System.debug('SecurityToken : ' + result.SecurityToken);

        System.assertEquals(1, result.AuthenticateResult);
    }
}
```

That test gives a positive response.

[image]

A couple of thoughts:

1. Change your line
   `req.setHeader('SOAPAction', ''); // Empty as in SOAPui` to 
   `req.setHeader('SOAPAction', 'blank'); // Empty as in SOAPui`
   See [Missing SOAP action header](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/49273/102)
2. What are you using to view the debug log? I checked both the Developer Console and out FuseIT Explorer. It is possible it is having encoding issues and is hiding some of the data.

Answer (score 1):

I have manually parsed SOAP XML responses using Apex with no problem - it is not Salesforce mangling the XML.

The response you are getting is a "invalid login and password" error message generated from the service that appears to be written in Visual Basic:

```
525<OAGToken><ERROR><ErrInfo>An unexpected VB error occured in clsWSAuthenticate.WSLogin</ErrInfo><ErrNumber>525</ErrNumber><ErrDescription>A customer_identifier element has invalid login and password combination.
</ErrDescription></ERROR></OAGToken>
```

So the problem looks to me like the remote service doesn't emit well-formed XML (let alone a valid SOAP response) when this error occurs.

Add the `ws:Authenticate` elements to your request XML to avoid the error.

**PS**

Sorry didn't read your question carefully enough to see that you are sending the `ws:Authenticate`. If OAG's documentation explains the difference between the error code 524 and 525 that might provide a hint. My only other guess would be to be more explicit in the headers you send:

```
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/soap+xml;charset=utf-8');
req.setHeader('Accept','application/soap+xml;charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: `ws:Authenticate` elements are added to the request XML in the code.

Agreed, output message from OAG seems invalid at `<SecurityToken xsi:type="xsd:string">`. How can I get the full raw answer in `getBody()` using the manual callout with `HTTPRequest`?

Comment: I performed the validation of the output message with SOAPui. Other validators show the output message as valid.

Comment: @PeterdeJong My mistake - see PS.

Comment: Corrected above examples with output using a valid subscription. Will try your suggestion.

Comment: Webservice borks using the header parameters you specified: `soap:Client
Server found request content type to be 'application/soap+xml;charset=utf-8', but expected 'text/xml'`. When using `text/xml;charset=utf-8` instead, there is no difference.

Comment: @PeterdeJong Doesn't sound like the best behaved service... I've used tcpmon to examine traffic - see e.g. [When “Generate from WSDL” fails – hand-coding web service calls](https://force201.wordpress.com/2010/05/20/when-generate-from-wsdl-fails-hand-coding-web-service-calls/) - allowing comparison of working and non-working cases at the HTTP level.